# AKS - Error from server (Forbidden): User cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to use the K8S through Azure AKS.

But when doing a simple command like: kubectl create namespace airflow

I get the following error message:

> Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User 
>   "xxx" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API 
>   group "" at the cluster scope

I have already commanded az aks get-credentials to connect to the cluster and then I try to create the namespace but without success.

Comment: Do you integrate it with Azure AD? Or what other features do you use?

Comment: I faced similar issue and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468588/1176573) worked for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case, this works when I use this command:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <RESOURCE GROUP NAME> --name <AKS Cluster Name> --admin
```

Comment: Yeah, it must work. But it has the admin permissions. Do you mean to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You dont have sufficient privileges to create namespace in the k8s cluster though you have access to the cluster

Check the below command to know if you have permission to create namespace

```
# kubectl auth can-i create namespace
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `/.kube/config` has been configured with correct user name and credentials. Then run the following command to set the context:

```
Kubectl config set-context —user=xx yourclustername
```

Comment: I had lots of old gunk in .kub/config. A rowdy round with kubectl config remove-xxx followed by az aks get-credentials finally put me back on track