# Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User cannot list resource "pods" in API group at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubeconfig

My private AKS Cluster is accessible only to the root user using `kubectl` on a jumphost. But for a non-root user it throws below error message:

```bash
someuser@jump-vm$ kubectl get pods -A
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "XX-XX-XX-XX-XX" cannot list resource "XX" in API group " " at the cluster scope
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: how did you obtain kubeconfig?

Comment: Not sure in past how it was created but we recently installed `kubelogin` to `/usr/bin`. Did not made any `kubeconfig`.

Comment: I'd think you are missing `az login` and `kubelogin convert` steps for the user

Comment: @4c74356b41 I deleted the `config` and `cache` from the `$HOME/.kube/*` and later re-initialized the config after `az login`. And it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case solution was to delete the old config from `$HOME/.kube/` and re-initialize it after `az login` with the user in question

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Azure VM from the private AKS cluster was being accessed was set to automatic restart which caused some issue with `kubectl` or `kubelogin`.

I followed below steps for both -- root as well as non-root user and after `kubectl` worked successfully.

```bash
root@jump-vm# cd ~ && cd .kube/
root@jump-vm# rm -r cache && rm config 
root@jump-vm# az login --tenant <tenant-id>
root@jump-vm# az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
root@jump-vm# az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-clutser-name>
root@jump-vm# kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli

someuser@jump-vm$ cd ~ && cd .kube/
someuser@jump-vm$ rm -r cache && rm config 
someuser@jump-vm$ az login --tenant <tenant-id>
someuser@jump-vm$ az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
someuser@jump-vm$ az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-clutser-name>
someuser@jump-vm$ kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli
```